# Stopping an AngularJS promise chain

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm trying to figure out a good way to say "Do all of these things, but bail in the case that any of them fails"

What I have right now:

```js
var defer = $q.defer();

this
    .load( thingy ) // returns a promise

    .then( this.doSomethingA.bind( this ) )
    .then( this.doSomethingB.bind( this ) )
    .then( this.doSomethingC.bind( this ) )
    .then( this.doSomethingD.bind( this ) )

    .then( function(){
        defer.resolve( this );
    } );
    ;

return defer.promise;
```

What I ultimately want is to somehow catch any error on that chain so I can pass it on to the `defer` promise above.  I don't particularly care if the syntax is kept similar to what I have above.

Or even if anyone can just tell me how to stop the above chain.

Comment: @user2246674 -- rejecting it doesn't seem to stop the chain though, the next one just continues

Comment: Don't know what I was thinking ..

Comment: This is a horrid example of the [deferred antipattern](http://stackoverflow.com/q/23803743/1048572)! Screw that `defer`, just `return` the `this.load(…).then(A).then(B).then(C).then(D);` chain!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do that same thing by:

```
var defer = $q.defer();

this
    .load( thingy ) // returns a promise

    .then( this.doSomethingA.bind( this ), $q.reject )
    .then( this.doSomethingB.bind( this ), $q.reject )
    .then( this.doSomethingC.bind( this ), $q.reject )
    .then( this.doSomethingD.bind( this ), $q.reject )

    .then( defer.resolve.bind( defer, this ), defer.reject.bind( defer ) );
    ;

return defer.promise;
```

Comment: This answer uses an anti-pattern and causes the user to repeat error handling.

Answer (score 7):

You can stop angularjs chain by returning rejected promise inside any then callback.

```
load()
.then(doA)
.then(doB)
.then(doC)
.then(doD);
```

where *doA*, *doB*, *doC*, *doD* can have logic like this:

```
var doA = function() {
    if(shouldFail) {
        return $q.reject();
    }
}
```

Comment: +1 What did it for me is the `return` part of `return $q.reject()`. Lots of searching led to all kinds of different ways, but to actually return the $q.reject() instead of just calling it is what actually kills the chain. Especially if you're trying to do something that isn't an HTTP failure, but a 'failure' in the sense that the model returned with an expected negative response.

Comment: Another way to stop the chain, say you want to show errors that happened during chain execution, you can just `throw new Error()`

Comment: Returning rejected promise will not stop the chain.

Answer (score 3):

I just stumbled across this and realized all these answers are terribly outdated. Here is the proper way to handle this for anyone that happens to find this post.

```
// Older code
return this.load(thing)
  .then(this.doA, $q.reject)
  .then(this.doB, $q.reject)
  .then(this.doC, $q.reject)
  .then(this.doD, $q.reject)
  .then(null, $q.reject);


// Updated code
// Returns the final promise with the success handlers and a unified error handler
return this.load(thing)
  .then(this.doA)
  .then(this.doB)
  .then(this.doC)
  .then(this.doD)
  .catch(this.handleErrors); // Alternatively, this can be left off if you just need to reject the promise since the promise is already rejected.
  // `.catch` is an alias for `.then(null, this.handleErrors);`
```

Comment: `.catch` didn't exist in angular's `$q` when this question was asked :)

Comment: @zyklus, you are correct but `.catch` is just an alias for `.then(null, fn)`. Which should have been valid then.

Comment: It didn't used to pass errors through, i.e. it would only catch errors from the previous `then`, which is why I wrote all the chain reject nonsense below.

Comment: If that was the case then using `$q.reject` as the second param to each `.then` would have been correct. I will leave my answer as an updated version that properly handles promises whereas the accepted answer still uses an anti-pattern.

Comment: Does not stop the chain. Catch returns a promise.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to handle this and also to catch the problem is the .catch block. Inside any .then block that you wanna kill the promise chain, yes use:

```
 return $q.reject();
```

However extend it like so...

```
 return $q.reject(new Error('Error Message Here'));
```

Now in the catch method you will have this

```
 .catch(function(err) {
     console.log(err); //This will log the above 'Error Message Here'
 });
```

Now we throw and handle the promise error correctly in the fashion promise failures were meant to be handled.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, this works but I don't like it...  Awaiting something better :)

It just seems dirty to create a promise for the sole sake of immediately rejecting it

```
myApp
    .factory( 'chainReject', [ '$q', function( $q ){
        return function( err ){
            var defer = $q.defer();
            defer.reject( err );

            return defer.promise;
        }
    } ] );

...

var defer = $q.defer();

this
    .load( thingy ) // returns a promise

    .then( this.doSomethingA.bind( this ), chainReject )
    .then( this.doSomethingB.bind( this ), chainReject )
    .then( this.doSomethingC.bind( this ), chainReject )
    .then( this.doSomethingD.bind( this ), chainReject )

    .then( defer.resolve.bind( defer, this ), defer.reject.bind( defer ) );
    ;

return defer.promise;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this use case [has been anticipated](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.%24q) and addressed with the use of $q.reject(reason)